# VMWare Player doesn't grab focus on alt-tab

Tags: linux, windows, vmware-player

(running Windows)

When alt-tabbing to the VMWare window, subsequent alt-tabs are to the host.  To obtain focus to VMWare, you need to click inside the window (removing your hand from the keyboard).  This is by design, but is there an option or workaround that will let you have VMWare take focus on alt-tab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible to do it automatically.

There is usually a shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl-G</kbd>  for VMWare Player on Windows) which will make VMWare grab the input (like clicking).

Comment: I ended up mapping Ctrl+Alt to Ctrl+G, since getting out of VMWare is symmetrically Ctrl+Alt.

AutoHotKey script: 
`Control & Alt::
Send, {Ctrl Down}g{Ctrl Up}
return`